# How I can solve this [RuntimeException] Elasticsearch-PHP requires cURL, or a custom HTTP handler?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, build

I have tried to build php with curl with brew (`brew install php --build-from-source`) then using the libphp7.so in apache. `php -m` shows that is has the curl module. This error outputs in Laravel logs and when running `composer update`:

> [RuntimeException] Elasticsearch-PHP requires cURL, or a custom HTTP handler

Comment: To be on the same page, you do realize that you have to have curl installed on both osx and also php right?

Comment: Can you check `phpinfo()` inside apache? While `php -m` might show that curl is installed, then it's possible that it's not yet available in apache (module not enabled, apache needs a restart, ...)

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand Well, if php -m tells me that it has curl then it has. And osx has curl by default.

Comment: @ChristophKluge The php ./configure was built with --with-curl and in phpinfo() and cURL support is enabled and cURL Information is 7.69.0

Comment: @RaimondsPlume this seems strange. May I ask to share a screenshot of the header area of `phpinfo()` inside your browser and additionally a code-snippet of the  vhost configuration for apache?